# Remove Textboxes

Tags: java, c#, jquery

I know this may be a simple question but I have been searching for a way to remove textboxes on a button click, i add the text boxes in with this line of code.

```
 function SearchAddressFields(){

        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<br> <label for='txtSearch'>Street Number:</label> <input type='text' id='txtStreetNum' />"
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<label for='txtSearch'>PreDir:</label> <input type='text' id='txtPreDir' />"
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<label for='txtSearch'>PreType:</label><input type='text' id='txtPreType' />   "
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<label for='txtSearch'>Street Name:</label><input type='text' id='txtStreetName' /> "
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<label for='txtSearch'>Suf Dir</label><input type='text' id='txtSufDir' />"
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<input type='button' id='btntest' onclick='searchAddress()' value='Search'/>"
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<input type='button' id ='reset' onclick='resetbutton()' value='Reset' />"          
  }
```

This is probably the wrong way to do it, but it works for me. Is there any way to get this to remove the elements if the same button is clicked again?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: `my_div.innerHTML = string.Empty` ?

Comment: You might be better off putting them in a hidden div on the page and hiding/showing that div based on whether they click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is tagged with "jquery", so hopefully this will help:

outside of your function, you could have another variable that tracks if the elements have been added:

```
var haveElementsBeenAdded = false;

function SearchAddressFields(){

    if(!haveElementsBeenAdded){
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<br> <label for='txtSearch'>Street Number:</label> <input type='text' id='txtStreetNum' />";
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<label for='txtSearch'>PreDir:</label> <input type='text' id='txtPreDir' />";
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<label for='txtSearch'>PreType:</label><input type='text' id='txtPreType' />   ";
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<label for='txtSearch'>Street Name:</label><input type='text' id='txtStreetName' /> ";
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<label for='txtSearch'>Suf Dir</label><input type='text' id='txtSufDir' />";
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<input type='button' id='btntest' onclick='searchAddress()' value='Search'/>"
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<input type='button' id ='reset' onclick='resetbutton()' value='Reset' />"    ;     
        haveElementsBeenAdded = true; 
    }
    else{
        $(my_div).find('input').remove();
        $(my_div).find('label').remove();   
        haveElementsBeenAdded = false; 
    }

}
```

The above does not remove the non-breaking space though.

Comment: Lol that worked but it removed my main button, if i was high enough to upvote your answer i would. Thank You

Comment: is there a reason it might be deleting my Main button?

Comment: If your main button is inside the "my_div" element and is an "<input>" element, then it will remove it. Try putting that button outside of the div, or alter the jquery to not include the submit button. Try: $(my_div).find('input').not('[type="button"]').remove();

Comment: Never mind i found it, but is there a way to just place it in the same div cause it keeps moving the row down@Jason Millikan

Comment: Thanks Alot!! Other people that are higher than me please upvote for him

Comment: Again, you're welcome! Be sure to check out the jquery API for more useful insights and examples: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Put a class on the text box such as class="HideTheseTextBoxes"

The use jQuery to hide those on the onclick event

```
$( ".HideTheseTextBoxes" ).hide();
```